# Double check simple SQL query - customer and orders tables

Tags: sql

I just wanted to double check this SQL query that I wrote. I want to return the top five customer first names based on the dollar amount ordered? I'm using a table called "customer" and table called "orders". However, I can't remember if I need to use a "max" somewhere.... Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT TOP 5
customer.customerFirstName

FROM customer
LEFT JOIN orders
    ON customer.customerID = orders.customerID

ORDER BY orders.orderCost DESC
```

Comment: Did you run it and see what happens?

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help

Comment: Your query looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to sql server on my work computer and I'm currently using my home computer to post this. I just wanted to double check to make sure the logic I'm using makes sense.

Comment: If you still wonder why, read about the order of execution: "ORDER BY" executes before "TOP" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-query

Comment: You may have more than 5 customers with the same value for `orderCost`, being it the maximum in the database. If it happens, do you still must select the top 5? Which 5 customers must be selected in this case... any of them?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by`, I think:

```
SELECT TOP 5 c.customerFirstName
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.customerID = o.customerID
GROUP BY c.customerFirstName
ORDER BY SUM(o.orderCost) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this should help answer your question, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
SELECT TOP 5 orders.orderid,
```

orders.customerid,
customers.customername 
From customers
LEFT JOIN orders 
ON customers.customerid=orders.customerid
ORDER by orders.orderid DESC