# Returning value from inside exists subquery without joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM collection
WHERE id = 1 AND (
    privacy = 0
    OR (privacy = 1 AND
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM collection_member WHERE collection_id = collection.id AND member_id = 1)
    )
)
```

This is working fine. However I also want to output result from `SELECT * FROM collection_member WHERE collection_id = collection.id AND member_id = 1`. What is the most efficient way to achieve this **without** using joins? (Edit: May be [subquery encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955955/1768337)?)

Comment: If you want the information from collection_member, you have to use a join. Why dont' you want to do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because this is only a simplified version of a bigger query that uses joins to fetch other data. So was wondering if there was another method.

Comment: There might be many matching members in collection_member. The table name certainly implies that. Which hone do you want? What reasoning do you have for not using a join?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually due to `AND member_id = 1`, it should match only one member.

Comment: Basically you need to use a join to return data from that table, either in the from clause or the select clause. Or you could use a cursor if you really don't want to use a join. That would be madness.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I was thinking along the lines of subquery encapsulation https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955955/1768337 though

Comment: That example of subquery encapsulation has only one table. You have two and they need to be joined. For simplicity you can pop the entire expression into a field in the select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that puts the subselect in as a column.

This is still a join but maybe it's closer to what you're after.

```
SELECT C.* , 
(SELECT MAX(M.MyColumn) 
 FROM collection_member M
 WHERE collection_id = C.id 
 AND M.member_id = 1
 ) MyColumn
FROM collection C
WHERE C.id = 1 
AND (
    C.privacy = 0
    OR (privacy = 1 AND
        EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM collection_member CM
        WHERE CM.collection_id = C.id AND CM.member_id = 1)
    )
)
```

Really the only benefits of this approach over performing the `JOIN` in the from, is that it's a little bit easier to make sure you are not joining many to many and double counting.

The query shown above uses `MAX` to ensure only one row is returned. This may or may not be the row that you want.

Comment: I guess this is the only way. With one caveat that the first subquery can return only 1 column right?

Comment: Yes only one column and also only one row.

Comment: If you need to return more than one column then you need to join the table properly in the `FROM` clause. Regardless, both of these approaches require joins. There's no explanation of why you don't want to do a join. As I mentioned the only non join option is a cursor, which is simply wrong

Comment: The really puzzling part of this question is the constraint "_without_ using joins". Why would you not want to use a join in a database? That's its strength. Subqueries are not a way to avoid joins - you still need to join the subquery and in some cases using a subquery hampers the qurey planner and impacts performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t “get values from an `exists` subquery”.

You have to join to it:

```
SELECT *
FROM collection
LEFT JOIN collection_member ON privacy = 0
  OR (privacy = 1
      AND collection_id = collection.id
      AND member_id = 1
  )
WHERE id = 1
```

Of course, unlike your query, `collection` rows will appear once  for *every matching row* in `collection_member`. You could deal with this by aggregating all `collection_member` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c.*, cm.*
FROM collection c
        Left Join collection_member cm on (cm.collection_id = c.collection.id and cm.member_id = 1)
WHERE case
        when c.privacy = 0 Then 1
        when c.privacy = 1 and cm.collection_id is not null Then 1
        else 0
      end = 1
and c.id = 1
```