# Return registers based on its score average

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, where-clause

table tb_students is following
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ukpJEHGLE5sKkHuqNjFKPZ/5

---

| id | first_name | last_name | test_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Smith | History | 0.8 |
| 2 | F | Snow | Math | 0.5 |
| 3 | F | Snow | History | 0.5 |
| 4 | A | Smith | English | 1.0 |
| 5 | C | Bayer | English | 1.5 |
| 6 | F | Snow | English | 1.5 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ukpJEHGLE5sKkHuqNjFKPZ/6)

I need to return all students whose avg test score on humanities test ("English" and "History)
is 1.0 or higher

```
select first_name, last_name, round(avg(score),1) as avg_score
from pruebas.tb_students
where test_name in ('History', 'English')
group by first_name, last_name
```

It throws an error when try to include in a WHERE statement `avg_score > 1.0`

Do I need implement some kind of subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to a column alias in the *where* or *having* clause since they are evaluated *before* the *select* (but yes you could if you used a derived table with an outer *select*);

This is a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955911/why-cant-i-use-column-aliases-in-the-next-select-expression).

You can simply repeat the expression using a *having* clause for filtering (the optimizer will only evaluate it once) :

```
having round(avg(score),1) >= 1;
```

`>=` since your question states *is 1.0 or higher*