# GROUP BY clause parsed before or after SELECT clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand the *logical* order of execution of the `SELECT` query in the MySQL DBMS.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order) questions  it came out that the order can be:

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. **GROUP BY**
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. **SELECT**
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Or:

> 1. FROM clause
> 2. WHERE clause
> 3. **SELECT clause**
> 4. **GROUP BY clause**
> 5. HAVING clause
> 6. ORDER BY clause

As you can see the order is inverse in the two, so I started fiddling with MySQL.

The table (`PROGETTO`) was the following:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| NOME_P   | varchar(15) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| NUMERO_P | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| SEDE_P   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_D    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

the dataset was:

```
+-----------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| NOME_P          | NUMERO_P | SEDE_P    | NUM_D |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| ProdottoX       |        1 | Bellaire  |     5 |
| ProdottoY       |        2 | Sugarland |     5 |
| ProdottoZ       |        3 | Houston   |     5 |
| Informatizzazio |       10 | Stafford  |     4 |
| Riorganizzazion |       20 | Houston   |     1 |
| Nuove opportuni |       30 | Stafford  |     4 |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

So, I launched the first query:

```
mysql> SELECT NOME_P FROM PROGETTO GROUP BY NUM_D;
+-----------------+
| NOME_P          |
+-----------------+
| Riorganizzazion |
| Informatizzazio |
| ProdottoX       |
+-----------------+
```

and I thought, "well the order must be the first one, but let's try another time..." and I executed:

```
mysql> SELECT NOME_P AS NNN FROM PROGETTO GROUP BY  NNN;
+-----------------+
| NNN             |
+-----------------+
| Informatizzazio |
| Nuove opportuni |
| ProdottoX       |
| ProdottoY       |
| ProdottoZ       |
| Riorganizzazion |
+-----------------+
```

...and this totally made me confused.

Comment: The difference in the results has nothing to do with *order of execution*. You are grouping by *two different fields*, hence the different output.

Comment: I'm talking about "NNN" not the result. Following the first one order WHERE can't access to the alias defined in the `SELECT` and so should be for `GROUP BY`, but it isn't

Comment: This is like an extension of the `GROUP BY` clause implemented by the MySQL engine. In another RDBMS like SQL Server you would get a syntax error for the same statement.