# MySQL Broken Rank

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

I have the following query which returns some event details, the number of votes and a rank.

```
SELECT e.guid, 
       e.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
        FROM event_vote sv 
        WHERE ev.event_uid = s.guid) AS votes,
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

---

It returns the correct details including votes but the rank is broken.

**Actual Result**

```
guid | name | votes | rank

def    test2     2      2
abc    test1     1      1 
ghi    test3     0      3
jkl    test4     0      4
```

**Expected Result**

```
guid | name | votes | rank

def    test2     2      1
abc    test1     1      2 
ghi    test3     0      3
jkl    test4     0      4
```

For some reason test1 has a higher rank than test2.

I assume I need to use a JOIN but i'm unsure on the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the votes first, then calculate the ranking.

```
SELECT T.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM ( SELECT e.guid, 
              e.name,
              (SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
               FROM event_vote sv 
               WHERE ev.event_uid = s.guid) AS votes
       FROM event e
    ) as T
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

You have wrong result because `SELECT` section occurs before `ORDER` section, so you already have a rank but not necessary match the order you get at the end.

Can read more about it here:

[Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)

Comment: I want to make this user specific by joining user_event.

I added "JOIN user_event ue ON t.guid = ue.selfie_uid
              WHERE ue.user_uid = '33c2fb85'" after AS T but this gives me the opposite answer (events NOT related to the user). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is better if you create a new question. I cant understand your query because isnt formated. You can link this question as reference but you need include all relevant information on the new question.