# MySQL join based on the first 4 characters

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join a second table based on the first 4 characters of a field from the first table but I keep getting "Unknown column 'questions.first4' in 'on clause'" and I'm not sure why:

```
SELECT questions.id as id, question, answer, correct, SUBSTRING(question,1,4) as first4
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.correct_answer = questions.first4
WHERE player_name = 'Alpha Squad'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

(I realize that the tables are structured inefficiently but unfortunately, I have to work with them as-is)

Tables: https://pastebin.com/Gur5ufXa

MySQL: https://pastebin.com/FLgWtQmY

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ""Unknown column 'questions.first4' in 'on clause'" and I'm not sure why:" Because there isn't a column first4 within the questions table

Comment: "based on the first 4 characters" - the right way to fix this is to normalize your schema

Comment: I recommend that *all* column references be qualified with a table name (or with a table alias) even if the column names aren't ambiguous. As a favor to future readers, and to avoid the query breaking when a column of the same name is later added to another table in the query. (The reason for the error is that the column alias `first4` is not available for reference in the ON clause or WHERE clause. Just replace the invalid reference to `first4` with the expression `SUBSTRING(questions.question,1,4)`

Comment: indeed @spencer7593 unaliased columns or unqualified columns can really cause problems when using co-related subquerys,, Besides it makes reading the query alot eazier because you directly know in which table the column is directing to thats why i always use fully qualified columns

Comment: The order of operation `FROM` `WHERE` `GROUP BY` `HAVING` `SELECT` `ORDER BY`.  So when it sees `LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.correct_answer = questions.first4`, it doesn't know what it means.

Comment: @RaymondNijland "`SUBSTRING(question,1,4)` .. can not use indexes" - `answers.correct_answer = SUBSTRING(question,1,4)` can use an index on `answers.correct_answer`. You can't even use an index from the left table in a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Eric - That has little to nothing to do with the logical or internal execution order. Column aliases are permited in GROUP BY and HAVING clauses but not in WHERE - though they all "come" before SELECT.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It has everything to do with the execution order.  In this example, OP alias column in `SELECT`, and try to use it in `JOIN` because he doesn't understand the order of execution.

Comment: @Eric .. SQL is not a procedural language - There is **no** execution order. If they wanted, they would permit aliases in the WHERE clause as they did for GROUP BY and HAVING. But they decided not to do - Thats all.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If you say there's no execution order in SQL, then you need to read this https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution , because that's exactly the OP's problem, aliasing a column in `SELECT` then trying to use it in `FROM/JOIN`

Comment: Thanks guys, I see what I did wrong now.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT questions.id as id, question, answer, correct, SUBSTRING(question,1,4) as first4
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.correct_answer = questions.correct
WHERE player_name = 'Alpha Squad'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

or this next one joins specifically on the ones with the matching first 4

```
SELECT questions.id as id, question, answer, correct, SUBSTRING(question,1,4) as first4
    FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN answers ON SUBSTRING(answers.correct_answer,1,4) = SUBSTRING(question,1,4)
    ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: This works great, thanks so much for your help!  Now I get it, finally.

Comment: This works perfectly to find all of the answers per team that have incorrect answers

`SELECT questions.id as id, question, answer, correct_answer, correct, SUBSTRING(question,1,4) as first4
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON SUBSTRING(answers.question_number,1,4) = SUBSTRING(question,1,4)
WHERE player_name = 'Alpha Squad' AND correct = 0`

Is there a way to use UPDATE to set correct = 3 for all of the results that this query returns?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.id as id, question, answer, correct, SUBSTRING(question,1,4) as first4
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.correct_answer = SUBSTRING(question,1,4) 
WHERE player_name = 'Alpha Squad'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

The problem is first4 doesnt exist at the moment you try to do the JOIN. Check here to see the order a select statment is processed.

[Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)