# I have 3 duplicate rows in Oracle Database. Want to delete only 2nd duplicate record. How do I do?

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:

```
sno Empid Ename Sal
1   100   xxx   1000
2   200   yyy   2000
3   200   yyy   2000
4   200   yyy   2000
```

`Empid`,`Ename`,`sal` are columns in the EMP table. `Sno` is not a column,its just for understanding

How to delete 3rd record?

Comment: why don't you want to delete the 4th record as well, since that's also a duplicate? And what have you researched or tried so far? This reads like a piece of homework.

Comment: Does it matter if you delete the 2nd duplicate instead of 1st or 3rd?

Comment: If they are duplicates in a relational table then there is no difference between them and it doesn't matter which is deleted.

Comment: i have faced this question in an interview. want to know the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
delete from example e
    where e.sno > (select distinct nth_value(e2.sno, 2) over (partition by e2.empid order by e2.sno)
                   from example e2
                   where e2.empid = e.empid  -- and other columns if necessary
                  );
```

This is using `nth_value()` to get the second value for each employee (if you want "duplicate" to mean all three columns then add conditions for them).

The `select distinct` is so the subquery returns only one value.  Unfortunately, there is no `nth_value()` as an aggregation function.

EDIT:

I think you can use `rowid`:

```
delete from example e
    where e.sno > (select distinct nth_value(e2.rowid, 2) over (partition by e2.empid order by e2.rowid)
                   from example e2
                   where e2.empid = e.empid  -- and other columns if necessary
                  );
```

Comment: sno is not a column of the table.

Comment: @KarthikaDavid . . . You should add a unique key to your table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 DELETE FROM emp 
 WHERE  ROWID = (SELECT Max(ROWID) 
                 FROM (SELECT ROWID, empid 
                       FROM emp 
                       WHERE  empid = 200 
                       ORDER  BY ROWID) 
                 WHERE  ROWNUM <= 2);
```

Comment: max(rowid) will return one value..then how did you filter data by rownum

Comment: the records get filtered first because where clause is executed prior to select clause. You may refer to the logical order of execution of a sql query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think theinterviewer wanted you to find the records which have 3 or more duplicates and delete 2nd (or any from the duplicates) from it.

Try this:

```
Delete from emp e
Where e.rowid in 
(select rid from 
 ( select t.rowid as rid, 
          Row_number() over (partition by t.empid, t.empno, t.sal order by 1) as rn,
          Count(1) over (partition by t.empid, t.empno, t.sal order by 1) as cnt
    From emp t) 
where cnt >= 3 and rn = 2) -- rn condition is irrelvant here but kept it here for satisfaction of interviewer :)
```

Cheers!!