# Why is a CTE needed to execute the following

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition-by

The following query errors with an invalid column name 'rowid'

```
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by sales_rep order by timestamp desc) as rowid, *
  FROM dbo.you_gettheidea
where rowid = 1
```

However, the following version works perfectly. I'm not sure why.

```
with t1 as (SELECT row_number() over (partition by sales_rep order by timestamp desc) as rowid, *
FROM dbo.you_gettheidea)

Select * from t1
Where rowid = 1
```

SQL Server 12.0.2000

Edit: It appears that this question is in line with the [following answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)

Comment: Look into SQL *order of execution*. The *where* clause has no visibility of the derived column *rowid*

Comment: If I am following [this](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/) correctly,  SELECT is 6th, while WHERE is 4th. Thus your comment about visibility makes sense. Thank you

Comment: If you'd followed that link correctly, `WHERE` is 2nd and `SELECT` is 6th, so the `WHERE` cannot see any results from later operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column alias in where clause of same statement. It doesn't obey the execution order that's why CTE is needed. Please check [Execution order](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution)

> 1. FROM and JOIN s. The FROM clause, and subsequent JOIN s are first executed to determine the total working set of data that is being
>    queried.
> 2. WHERE.
> 3. GROUP BY.
> 4. HAVING.
> 5. SELECT.
> 6. DISTINCT.
> 7. ORDER BY.
> 8. LIMIT / OFFSET / TOP

Comment: Yes, this is the answer.

Comment: Just a comment, the JOIN's are part of the FROM clause.

Comment: Yes! definitely it is. Thanks. I just mentioned the orders from the linked addresses for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but there is another option without a CTE or subquery ... `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  dbo.you_gettheidea
 Order By row_number() over (partition by sales_rep order by timestamp desc)
```

Comment: I could not get `with ties` to work at all for my purposes. The version of SQL I am running kept trying to interpret it as a CTE.

Comment: @ZdWhite Without more context, it is hard to visualize your problem.   Just for fun, here is a working example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=14a11693b4027884d413b34365407743

Comment: hmm well upon retrying this method I did get it to work. The results seem slightly out of order, not sure why but it's seemingly inconsequential. I like this alternative as it is far cleaner than sub-queries or even my preferred CTE. Thank you!

Comment: @ZdWhite Full Disclosure:  The cte approach ... where RN=1 is a nudge more performant

Comment: Oh? Care to explain, my intuition for SQL performance isn't quite there yet.

Comment: @ZdWhite WITH TIES requires a SORT and this can get expensive with really LARGE tables.

Comment: @ZdWhite I do like this method because there are no extra columns i.e. RN.   That said, if my table is millions of rows, I will use the CTE

Comment: Thank you for the context, I'm dealing with rows on the order of 10^3 eventually ~10^4th and like 10 columns on an operation/table that updates ~ once a week. So I'm not particularly worried about performance but I'd like to be generally aware.