# Subquery with inner join

Tags: postgresql, subquery, inner-join

```sql
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN payment p ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = p.customer_id
WHERE p.amount > (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM payment)
INNER JOIN city ON city_id = c.city.city_id
WHERE c.city LIKE '%a%'
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
> LINE 6: INNER JOIN city
>         ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 155
> ```

Comment: A couple of doubts here, I need some more data.
On the 4th line `ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = p.customer_id` why `C` and not `c`? I expect a small `c` and not a capital one.

You are accessing `ON city_id = c.city.city_id` on line 7. How come this is possible `c.city LIKE '%a%'` shows that `c.city` is strings then `c.city.city_id` is not accessible.

Comment: Just a mistake on my part having caps on. It should be lower case but it will run regardless if syntax is correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

Second "INNER JOIN" must be before "WHERE"

```
SELECT 
    c.first_name, 
    c.last_name
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN payment p ON (p.customer_id = c.CUSTOMER_ID)
INNER JOIN city ON (city.city_id = c.city_id)
WHERE 
    p.amount > (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM payment)
    AND city.city LIKE '%a%'
```