# Does WHERE clause in SQL scan the database then filter?

Tags: sql, database

Other than data sent over the wire, from a performance perspective, does using a `WHERE` clause in SQL query improve the performance or it makes no difference.

Curious on how database works internally and whether `WHERE` clause is just a scan + filter operation? Or is there a way to improve `WHERE` clause performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)

Comment: The `WHERE` clause, as you have mentioned, acts like a filter, which potentially reduces the size of a result set, and therefore also may reduce the bandwidth needed.

Comment: Download the source code and check for yourself how it works. And yes, it makes a massive difference in performance

Comment: See https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause

Comment: Regarding "*is there a way to improve WHERE clause performance?*" This style of question has launched a thousand websites and many more books & blogs. Yes, there are many things that can be done to perform efficient filtering (or the reverse, to do it badly) - but it takes more space that an answer block here to treat this properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you are referred to "[Order Of Execution of the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596467/order-of-execution-of-the-sql-query)" and you are well advised to read the excellent answers to that question. In [one of those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596739/2067753)  it states:

> The optimizer is free to choose any order it feels appropriate to produce the best execution time.

Keep this true statement in mind, because we tend to think that WHERE follows FROM because that's how we write out the query; but WHERE can be coupled (or perhaps better described as "moved around" a bit) in the early stages of the query execution.

e,g. we might write a query like this:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, c.customer_name
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c ON  o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE o.order_date >= '2023-01-01';
```

but the actual execution might folow something more like this:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date >= '2023-01-01') o
JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id;
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, c.customer_name
```

because filtering the orders table before joining it processes a smaller set of data which could lead to improved query performance.

This isn't a trivial topic, and this tiny example is wholly inadequate to describe the inner complexities of how SQL queries are executed. What I would simply like to impart is that, yes, WHERE predicates filter the data, but don't get into the mindset that assumes WHERE sequentially follows FROM because it does not have to be.

Similarly, because WHERE does filtering, and is an intimate partner of the FROM clause, it does have a massive influence on query performance.